# Patching Process in AIX

Tags: aix

I joined a new company and they are using AIX.
So I have just a few patches but NOWHERE on the internet could I find how to download the patches.
The machines are not connected to the internet.

Comment: Could you give an example of a patch you can't find?

Comment: What patches are you talking about? What is your actual question, are you asking how to find patches or how to apply them?

Comment: I am trying to find out how to apply them..

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. But I managed to find the patches over here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/faqs.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about patching the operating system, or a range of related products (such as PowerVM, PowerHA, etc.) then you usually start at IBM Fix Central.

https://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/

There's not much to be said in terms of an answer, other than go there, fill in the drop downs with your product information, and the site builds a list of packages to download.

For AIX, you would normally get a TL (technology level) or SP (service pack) set of files, whack them on the server, and use the relevant OS commands to do an apply.

This link https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012517 has the latest patch cycles for AIX.

Answer (score 1):

https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/
Select Product
Product Group - IBM Operating Systems
Select the version which you want to install - AIX 6.1
Fix type - Fix packs
Select the fixes which you want to upgrade your system
select the Download options

basically, IBM do no longer ship single fixes, except for Emergency Fixes to correct really high pervasive errors and Security Fixes to fill security holes.

Instead, they deliver Technology Level packages to contain major fixes/revisions/enhancements and, between TLs , there are Service Packages to contain just fixes (in most cases).

Emergency/Security fixes as well as TL/SP packages can all be downloaded from IBM Fix Central:
http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/

There is also a tool called SUMA (Service Update Management Assistant) to automatically search for fix packages and to download them at regular intervals.

There are several nice papers dealing with the IBM AIX Service Strategy.

These are the central documents on our topic:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/pow03060usen/POW03060USEN.PDF
https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/best/aix_service_strategy_v3.pdf

And this is for SUMA:
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_p_os_aix_whitepapers_suma.pdf

Here is another "Best Practices" paper containing information on how to use the various service tools:
http://rdsrc.us/qrhP6d

The actual process of applying service to AIX is rather simple with SMIT.

Once you downloaded a package (or a single Security fix) just run

"smitty install_update"

You can the choose between installing new software components ("Install Software"), applying a TL or SP package ("Update Installed Software to Latest Level (Update All)") or to install single fixes (" Update Software by Fix").

The following menus all require specifying the directory you downloaded the software to, and several additional options which you can mostly leave on their defaults, except for the option "ACCEPT new license agreements?" where you must always specify "yes" ("no" is the default).

The update process will then run automatically, and at the end you will be informed whether a reboot at a time of your choice will be required (a reboot is always required after applying a TL or SP).

The starting point for installing Emergency Fixes is slightly different, you will reach the appropriate menus with "smitty emgr".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to apply patches (AIX speaks of updates) would be - after having downloaded them from somewhere:

```
# smitty update_all
```

And answer the questions in the dialogs that follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up and use suma. Its IBM's manual way to automate updates. Its not as nice as ... well any other OS patching you've probably ever done but it can be set up to run in a cron job. However you will need to have a software maintenance agreement with IBM to get any software updates for the software you already purchased and suma will error unless you have a hardware maintenance contract for the hardware its on. There you go easy peesy. well I'm off to use linux!

Comment: [pavan’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506577/80216) already mentions SUMA, and you don’t seem to be providing enough new information to justify posting an answer.  ‘‘you will need to have a software maintenance agreement with IBM’’ is a comment. You could maybe make this an answer by describing how to use SUMA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).